# 'Browse' button in HTML form not working in IE 7 or 8 (ietester)

Tags: html, internet-explorer, forms, upload

I have a really straight forward image upload form in a website of mine. For some reason, when I load up ieTester and use IE 8 or IE7, the 'Browse' button to locate the file has no text on it, and it also doesn't open a file selection dialogue.

Does anybody know why this might be? Could it be because I'm using IE Tester?

Here's the code for my form:

```
<form action="edit-profile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="file" id="file" type="file" />
    <input type="hidden" name="uploaded" value="true" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: yes try to disabled ie tester and try

Comment: change name and id something instead of file

Comment: @Anand tried, no luck unfortunately.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the current version of IETester/DebugBar.  [It has been reported](http://www.my-debugbar.com/forum/t770-input-type%3A-file-does-work-with.html), although not yet acknowledged or dealt with.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this approach and it is working in IE8,9. Please check if redesign of browse button is the issue. Consider demo first.
[HTML Campus](http://htmlcampus.com/style-a-file-browse-button-with-css/)